# Call Cloud Run for every item in a database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-run

I'm currently working on a project that I want to move into the cloud so I can scale to multiple users. Basically, I want to grab the name for every user from my database (thinking about using Firestore for this), and for each of those names I want to call a python script every 24 hours (will use a Cloud Scheduler job). I envision that I would use Cloud Run, since I would want multiple instances of the python script running at the same time (one for every user) and I would want it to be serverless since I would only be running it once a day.

My questions are:

- Are the cloud services I chose the correct ones for the job? For instance, is there a better service than Cloud Run to launch the script?
- Is there built-in functionality to pass in entries in Firestore and launch a Cloud Run instance for each? I see, for instance, that issue [Does it make sense to run a non web application on cloud run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62804653/does-it-make-sense-to-run-a-non-web-application-on-cloud-run) is very close to my question, but they do not interact with the database element

Comment: Its going to be difficult to advise on your architecture choice without more details.  For example, does your database have 10 user names in it or 10 million?  How long (elapsed time) does it take to process all users?  What is the impact on your solution of a crash or if a user isn't processed?  What are the factors influencing your design ... do you want something that works and is easy to maintain quickly or are you optimizing for volume or optimizing for price or optimizing for availability or something else?

Comment: @Kolban Thank you for your reply. The number of users will be small scale, I would estimate 10-20 user max. Each run of the python script would take around a minute to process completely, and I would hope that all instances would run in parallel. A crash would not be that drastic, this is a low-risk script that I would be running. Since I would be in the free tier for most products as a result of my scale, I am optimizing for something that's easy to create and maintain.

Comment: Based on what youve said, I'm getting the impression that a single Cloud Run or Cloud Functions may be an option.  I'm imagining Cloud Scheduler firing of a REST request at a given time and Cloud Run/Functions catching that, retrieving all the names from Firestore and then running the Python code (serially) for each name.  That feels like the easiest and least complex and most understandable solution.  Parallelism seems like overkill and scale at the quantities you suggest isn't an issue.

Comment: You have today a small number of users. However, will this number grow in the future?